# unrecognized selector sent to instance date picker - swift

Tags: ios, swift

Simulator crashes after selecting a date from the picker. No idea why (noob here)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dataPickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker){
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    dateLabel.text = strDate

}
```

Comment: Is `Selector()` new? I've always just passed a string in for the action value. But that could be something I missed in one of the recent betas.

Comment: Also, can you post your crash log/stack trace?

Comment: I'm using beta5 of Xcode6... log below:

2014-08-14 12:45:11.383 DatePicker[9336:455915] -[DatePicker.ViewController dataPickerChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb318c4a2b0
2014-08-14 12:45:11.386 DatePicker[9336:455915] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DatePicker.ViewController dataPickerChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb318c4a2b0'

Comment: -1 for not including the exception data in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is called "datePickerChanged", but in your `addTarget` call you've called it "dataPickerChanged". Should be:

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Comment: Look at the string inside `Selector(...)` -- it's "dataPickerChanged". That's "data", with an "a", while your method is "date", with an "e".

Comment: If it is crashing even after typing everything correctly, then try setting minimum and maximum date.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```